# Update local copy in my PC of a git branch

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a branch to my PC using:

```
git clone -b testRelease https://github.com/XXXX.git
```

Now, the remote branch changed some units.
How do I update my local copy of that branch, without to clone the branch repo again?

Regards, Luiz

Comment: I'd suggest to read a git tutorial, since git has more complexity to offer (by far) than how to update a local branch from the remote. Also, GitHub has a git cheat sheet which may be of future use to you: https://github.github.com/training-kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Use `git fetch` to download objects from the remote's branch and then `git merge` the changes you want to your local repository
- Or as a shortcut use `git pull` which is basically a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` from the latest commit of the fetched branch.

Documentation:

- `git fetch`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch
- `git merge`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
- `git pull`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull